# Core data query inserts new objects in managed object context

Tags: macos, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have a method in my OSX app that fetches all elements of a given type (`GEElementType` is an enum). It works fine most of the time, but under certain circumstances `[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:]` ends up calling `[NSManagedObject initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:]` several times adding new objects to the MOC... Is this an expected behavior at all? I can reproduce this consistently, but I don't understand why it works like this.

Here's a code excerpt:

```
+ (NSArray*)elementsOfType:(GEElementType)elementType
{
    return [GEElement findAllObjectsWithPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"elemtype == %d", elementType]];
}

+ (NSArray*)findAllObjectsWithPredicate:(NSPredicate*)predicate
{
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [GEDataManager sharedInstance].managedObjectContext;

    NSEntityDescription* entity = [self entityDescription];
    NSFetchRequest* request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError* error = nil;
    NSArray* result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription);
    }

    return result;
}
```

If it makes any difference, I'm using a Mogenerator with a custom base NSManagedObject subclass.

I added a breakpoint in my subclass' init and here's the stack trace:

```
#0  0x000000010003bf5a in -[GEElement initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:] at /.../DataModel/Human/GEElement.m:27
#1  0x00007fff89166abc in -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _initWithEntity:withID:withHandler:withContext:] ()
#2  0x00007fff8916540e in -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] ()
#3  0x00007fff891be7f6 in -[NSMappedObjectStore executeFetchRequest:withContext:] ()
#4  0x00007fff89154e63 in -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator executeRequest:withContext:error:] ()
#5  0x00007fff89152c1b in -[NSManagedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:error:] ()
#6  0x000000010000e50c in +[GEDataModelBase findAllObjectsWithPredicate:] at /.../DataModel/GEDataModelBase.m:72
#7  0x00000001000c04da in +[GEElementTypes elementsOfType:] at /.../Helpers/GEElementTypes.m:75
...etc...
```

EDIT: Here's the GEElement init method, as requested. Line 27 is the first one.

```
- (id)initWithEntity:(NSEntityDescription*)entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context
{
    self = [super initWithEntity:entity insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
    if (self)
    {
        // ...A bunch of property initializations here...
    }
    return self;
}
```

I can post all the property initializations if necessary, but there's nothing fancy going on there.

Comment: Can you update your question with the method in GEElement that contains line 27?

Comment: And I take it you are using an XML store?

Comment: Hey quellish, I updated my question with the GEElement init method that includes line 27 (the very first one). I'm using an in-memory store that I load from a JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok... so I finally figured out what was happening on my app that caused this issue.

After some digging, I found another unexpected behavior happening right before the multiple inserts issue: a bunch of my `GEElement`s were getting released but *without being deleted from the MOC*. I was accidentally removing some objects form the only array that held a strong reference to them. So I fixed my issue by adding the following when creating the MOC:

```
managedObjectContext.retainsRegisteredObjects = YES;
```

Apparently, the MOC was not retaining the objects and they got released but when I attempted to run a query, it recreated the missing objects... Is that an expected behavior?